# Confirm before delete malfunctioning

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have two repositories for the same project (long story - I'm trying to learn well, so I wanted to do it again for good measure). In one project, there is a confirm message before deleting, and there's a glyphicon trashcan on the delete button as well. In the other (current) one, neither the confirm message nor the trashcan are working (but the song does indeed delete).

The main issue here is not the trashcan, but rather that `data { confirm: ... }` is not working.

In the working version, the code looks like this:

```
<td><%= button_to delete_song_path(song_id: song.id), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: 'btn-mini btn-danger btn' do %>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
            <% end %></td>
```

In the other non-working version, the code looks like this:

```
<td><%= button_to destroy_user_song_path(@song), data: { confirm: "Aight, are you sure?" }, class: 'btn-mini btn-danger btn' do %>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                  <% end %></td>
```

For the trashcan, I did some "reverse elimination" of the working version, and found that although I have all the same bootstrap gems downloaded, the line of code that made the trashcan stay / go away was `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";' in application.css.scss. However, doing the same thing in the other project didn't work, so it must be the fact that in the working version, there are glyphicon files in the public-fonts file. If that's the culprit, I'll deal with that later once I have all the other base functionality down.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm 99% sure its a javascript issue. Check the browser console. A missing font or stylesheet issues will not cause the rails UJS confirm dialog to fail.

Comment: Ya, definitely was JS: I actually managed to fix it inadvertently a few minutes ago by getting rid of all the bootstrap gems and instead using a CDN for the css and js. Now the issue is that when I click "cancel", the button completely changes and shows some text inside of it from another page. I think it has to do with the way my classes are set up, but I'll def be able to figure that out. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and answer this since I got it to work: I'm not 100% sure on the exact cause of the problem, but what I do know is that I decided to simplify things and get rid of all bootstrap gems, instead opting to use a CDN file from netdna.bootstrap.com for bootstrap 3.3.7, and everything fixed itself.

So in sum, simple seems to be the best way to go for those like me who have little to no experience. As a side note, I also defined a helper file in the helper directory in order to define a variable for the bootstrap version. This way, in the future I can switch versions of bootstrap by simply replacing the variable with the correct version.